# How should I name the chord in the following progression? Dsus4/Bb? Bbmaj13?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I'm struggling to work out how to name the second chord in the following progression from a song I am transcribing:

[image: sheet music]

It's a sort of Dsus4 inversion with a b6 in the bass. My best guess is that it should be called a Dsus4/Bb or something like that, but I'm not really sure where to begin (Bbmaj13 perhaps?). It's a bit of an odd one, but the voice leading from b6>6 and 4>3 to Bm is nice.

Do you have any idea what it should be called? More generally do you have any tips for naming tricky chords like this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dsus/Bb will get the right notes played.  I don't think there's any point in trying to go further.   At least in this case there IS a simple, unambiguous chord name available.  Quite often there isn't.

When chords get TOO tricky, give up on chord symbols.  Fortunately we have notation...

Comment: As there are two distinct sus chords - 2 and 4, it only makes sense when the appropriate number is included. Just sus doesn't hack it.  It *is* ambiguous!

Comment: Not really.   In the absence of further information 'sus' means 'sus4'.   Look at ... well, any music that uses chord symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like Gm add9/Bb to me! G minor in 1st inversion, with an added A.